# Embedded QR code image from google charts api is redirecting to broken https URL

Tags: https, google-visualization

I have a QR code image that's embedded from the Google Charts API. Recently it stopped working, but I haven't changed anything in my code.

Here's the page (note the broken images): [redacted]

As you can see, the images are embedded as http:// but when they are loaded, they're redirecting to the https:// URL on the google domain, which is broken.

Why is this redirect happening?

Edit: forgot to add -- what's even stranger is that if you view the image in a new tab, then change http to https (in effect, making the url the exact one that was originally requested), 
 it loads fine.

Edit #2 removed the link to my test site, as I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the google charts domain has changed. The new one is:

`https://chart.googleapis.com`

do not use

`http://chart.apis.google.com`